# Split in py. write in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
 asd = "qweasdzxc";
 qwen = asd.split("")
 self.response.out.write(qwen[0]) # write q
```

i can split the sentence with this way but i want to do this with using django template in my html doc.

How can i do this

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for django for this. Here is a [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/211/) for splitting.

There is also [make_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#make-list) and slice (look on the same page as the last link) to accomplish the same goal.

Given the example slice is probably what you want.